# Get all selected cells in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the following code to get selected cells:

```
var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
```

If I select cells B1, B2, B3 it returns "B1:B3". But if I select B1 and then use the Ctrl key to also select B3 it returns only "B3". I want "B1,B3". I couldn't find a function for this in the documentation.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error. Is this being run by a trigger or something?

Comment: Do you mean that if you select B1 and B3, getActiveRange() is returning B3 only? If so, if you select B3 and then B1, do you get B1 only?

Comment: yes. whenever the range is not continuous, only last cell is returned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apps Script currently does not provide support for handling disjoint ranges within Range objects. What will happen is that the last selected sub-range will be returned by calls of getActiveRange(), etc. It is filed [here as issue 4069](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4069). You may want to 'star' it.

Answer (score 9):

```
  var range = '';
  var sel = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for(var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++){
    range += sel[i].getA1Notation() + ', ';
  }
  Logger.log(range);
```

Logs:
[18-06-21 22:18:16:866 EEST] B1, B3,

Answer (score 1):

Building on @ugene's answer, I came up with a function that returns all selected values:

It returns a 1-dimensional array of all the values in all the selected cells.

**Note**: My function `addRange` has nothing to do with google sheets ranges. It means "add a range of values to an array" and the terminology is a holdover from `LINQ` in `C#`. Sorry for any confusion.

**sheets.gs**

```
  function getSelectedValues() {
    return SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getSelection()
    .getActiveRangeList()
    .getRanges()
    .reduce(function(acc,curr) {
      acc.addRange(
        curr.getValues()
        .reduce(function(acc,curr) {
          acc.addRange(
            curr
            .reduce(function(acc,curr) {
              acc.push(curr);
              return acc;
            }, [])
          );
          return acc;
        }, [])
      );
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }
```

**arrays.gs**

```
Array.prototype.addRange = function(array) {
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    this.push(item);
  }, this);
}
```